# Google maps app works on Android 9.0 but not lower

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova

I recently started programming with cordova (using eclipse) for a Google map multiplatform app.

Currently, I am only working on android builds.

The app works well on Android with API 28, it shows a yellow flash screen with blue words then the google maps, makes a call to retrieve some data from my data base and shows it on the map. There is also a lateral  black menu bar (working on that content).

But, if I try to execute this app on an Android 7.0 (API 24) or basically any other API lower than 28. The flash screen is completely white with blue words instead of yellow and the Google maps doesn't load (the side black menu does).

I have done some debugging to that and the app still does the call to my data base and retrieves the information. It doesn't show any error (it showed some but I corrected them and didn't solve this issue).

Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be?

Thanks a lot to all of you.

EDIT:

Here is the code and some new logs i got after trying to solve the problem.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/lm8fbsk6v97frq3/www.rar?dl=0

in the map API inicialization i had to take out the our API key since i am not allowed to share it.

Thanks for your interest with my problem. Ask me anything.

Comment: Are there any error/warning logs in your console?

Comment: No, there are not. The log is the same in both versions

Comment: Can you please post your code so that we can reproduce this and screenshots of what your map looks like? Have you tried different devices and does this issue happen for any API below 28? Also can you please do some debugging from your side, e.g. is your map initialized? returning undefined? is your onMapReady function called?

Comment: There is no onMapready function since in API28 worked without problem. I have been doing some debugging from my side with the help of a coworker with more experience in Eclipse/cordova and we did not find something suspicious (we solved some errores but nothing changed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran your app on a Nexus S Android 7.0 (API 24) emulator and indeed, your map did not show up at all.

I changed its height from 100% to a fixed size such as `height:400px` and then it loaded without issues. Switching back to `height:100%` and then adding `position:absolute` also worked, and so did wrapping the map in a containing `<div>` with a given height.

The thing is, a Google map needs to have an explicit height set in order to be displayed at all, but your map and body both **do** have a height, so upon further code inspection I noticed you're using [jquery mobile](https://jquerymobile.com/) which has its own CSS. I removed both your jquery mobile's JS and CSS scripts and voila! The map's right there. :)

[image]

Comment: Hello eva, thanks for this. I think thats the solution to my problem but for some reason i cant make it work myself. I have added position absolute and a fixed height to the map, also i removed jquery.css. But, instead of loading the map, it appears a Big string that reads LOADING. The flash screen has recovered its original colour so i believe that what you are explaining is the right solution.

Comment: Have you removed both jquery mobile's CSS and JS dependencies? Or doing this e.g.: `<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position:absolute;"></div>` or this: `<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>`. All these workarounds work for me with your exact code. Looking forward to your update.

Comment: ah, now it worked! it seems i had both missplaced the position absolute and the ". Now it is working. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to hear!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the google play version of your emulator to see if its compatible. On my emulator, and old version of the google maps API would not register or load unless I had fully updated the play store. This could be fixed by downgrading the version of the google maps API you are currently using to a previous version.

Comment: I have tried with changing the version to an older one (like v=3.35 for example) and seeing that my google play store was updated. Didnt change anything, but thank you.